# grep only the first match in a line with regular expression

Tags: linux, grep, pattern-matching

I have some xml files, and I would like to do some pre-processing before I parse them into csv files in Python (memory issues).

Say I want to grep something whose title includes "abcd" from a xml file like

```
<Title> Project abcd </Title> <Id> xxxx</Id> <Group>xxxx</Group>... <Title> Project abcd </Title>
```

Because of the duplicated Title field, if I do

```
grep -Ei "<Title>.*abcd.* </Title>"
```

it will return the line if "abcd" is coincidentally contained in Id or other unrelated fields.

Is there a way that I can use grep to return the lines that only the Title field includes the pattern I want to find?

Answer (score 0):

You should know the risk, to parse html/xml by regex. If you have to do it,
try

```
'<Title>[^<]*abcd[^<]*</Title>'
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need for now. I did not know the risk though, will learn to use xml parser for future proj.

Answer (score 0):

Using xml/html parsers is the right way to manipulate xml/html data:

**xmlstarlet** solution:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -c "//Title[contains(text(),"abcd")]" -n your.xml
```

The output (for your current input):

```
<Title> Project abcd </Title><Title> Project abcd </Title>
```